# How to add Mbeans to a remote server?

Tags: java, jmx, visualvm, mbeans

Typically, programatically adding an MBean to a local process is simple. You would do something like this:

```
// Assuming you have already written code for your MBean
MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
server.registerMBean(Object, ObjectName);
```

However, is there a way to add an Mbean to a remote server? As far as I know, there is no way to retrieve the MBeanServer of a remote process. I know you can retrieve the MBeanServerConnection, but this would only allow you to access Mbeans, not modify/add new ones.

Thanks!

Comment: I seriously doubt you can do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but there are some additional challenges. The issue is that you must have the MBean implementation and all supporting classes in the classpath of the target MBeanServer. If you do, then you can use one of the [MBeanServerConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html) createMBean methods to create and register the MBean. Two of them use the default classpath:

- [ObjectInstance createMBean(String className, ObjectName name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#createMBean-java.lang.String-javax.management.ObjectName-)
- [ObjectInstance createMBean(String className, ObjectName name, Object[] params, String[] signature)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#createMBean-java.lang.String-javax.management.ObjectName-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.String:A-)

If your target (or supporting) classes are not in the default classpath, you can dynamically load them when registering which is a bit trickier and require using a loader MBean which serves as the classloader for the create and registration operation:

- [ObjectInstance createMBean(String className, ObjectName name, ObjectName loaderName)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#createMBean-java.lang.String-javax.management.ObjectName-javax.management.ObjectName-)
- [ObjectInstance createMBean(String className, ObjectName name, ObjectName loaderName, Object[] params, String[] signature)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#createMBean-java.lang.String-javax.management.ObjectName-javax.management.ObjectName-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.String:A-)

The parameter named *loaderName* represents the ObjectName of an MBean which represents a classloader that can classload the operation. This will be a classloader with a management interface allowing it to be registered as an MBean. This could be a custom wrapped classloader, or the JRE included [MLet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/loading/MLet.html).

Answer (score 0):

MbeanServerConnection has methods to [createMBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#createMBean-java.lang.String-javax.management.ObjectName-).

Example:

```html
final MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
String domain = beanConn.getDefaultDomain();
            
String className = "com.example.mbean.SampleClass";
ObjectName name = new ObjectName(domain + ":name=" + className);
beanConn.createMBean(className, name);
```